# How to get SXA datasource items from personalization

Tags: sxa, personalization, datasource

I'm trying to get all datasources of a rendering, including personalization.

As we are using SXA the datasource strings look like this: local:/Data/Test
What is the best way to get the item from this? Normally the **getRenderingDatasource pipeline** would handle this, but how do I do this programmatically?

Comment: Once you have this information, how might you make use of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy:

```
//inject pipeline manager (instead of ServiceLocator you can use constructor injection if needed)
BaseCorePipelineManager pipelineManager = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<BaseCorePipelineManager>();

//create pipeline arguments where you put data source string
var args = new ResolveRenderingDatasourceArgs(rendering.DataSource);

//run the pipeline
pipelineManager.Run("resolveRenderingDatasource", args);
```

As an output, you will have either ID or an item path in `args.Datasource` property.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot :)  But I had to do it this way (although having the correct usings): ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(BaseCorePipelineManager)) as BaseCorePipelineManager

Comment: Just such using `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;` and you will be able to use `GetService` like that: `ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<BaseCorePipelineManager>()`.

Comment: You will need to add `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` and `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` nuget packages for this.

Comment: I added the first dll, but not the Abstractions one. That explains it. Thanks!